# How to show different data on button click in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two buttons and I am trying to show different data based on clicking particular button(ng-click)

**Update:** I have a thrid button which is not working with `data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN';Data1=true;"`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <li ><a data-ng-click="Data1=true;Data2=false" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
  <li ><a data-ng-click="Data2=true;Data1=false" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a></li>
  <li  ng-if="role === 'admin'" ><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN' , Data1=true;" href="">SAVED PROJECTS</a></li>

  <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2 ng-hide=Data2 ng-show="Data1">This is mah Data1, yo!</h2>
    <h2 ng-hide=Data1 ng-show="Data2">This is mah Data2, yo!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update2:** This is my actual list data

```
<ul class="list_of_projects row">                                   
        <li ng-show="Data1" ng-repeat="wd in workOrdersList | filter: search.status | filter: search.name | itemsPerPage: 10">
            <a href="">
                <h4>{{wd.name}}</h4>
            </a>
            <p>Status: {{wd.status}}</p>
        </li>
        <li ng-show="Data2">Data2</li>
    </ul>
    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

How do I hide data of first button(Data1) when I click on second(Data2) and viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
In that case you do need two booleans :

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li ><a data-ng-click="Data1=true;Data2=false" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li ><a data-ng-click="Data2=true;Data1=false" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a></li>
    <li  ng-if="role === 'admin'" ><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN'; Data1=true;" href="">SAVED PROJECTS</a></li>

    <h2 ng-show="Data1">This is mah Data1, yo!</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="Data2">This is mah Data2, yo!</h2>
</div>
```

Make sure you put the buttons and data in the same controller to prevent scoping issues.

Check out working example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uuRU4lZZYsJna9fP4rVa?p=preview)

Comment: I have one more button like this: `<li  ng-if="role === 'admin'" ><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN' , Data1=true;" href="">SAVED PROJECTS</a></li>`

Comment: Its not working bro. I have checked the plunker and removed the ng-if also

Comment: I have updated Plunker. There is a typo :  change , to ; in the 3rd button ng-click

Comment: If you want to hide Data2 with 3rd button, you can add `Data2=false;` to the ng-click aswell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114354/discussion-between-tom-shen-and-satyadev).

Answer (score 1):

Please check working example : [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hgn6Ya?p=preview)

In Html

```
<button ng-click="showData = 1">Show Data 1</button>
<button ng-click="showData = 2">Show Data 2</button>

<div ng-if="showData == 1">Data1</div>
<div ng-if="showData == 2">Data2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <button ng-click="Data1=true;Data2=false">Data 1</button> 
  <button ng-click="Data2=true;Data1=false">Data2</button>
```

Comment: I have a thrid button which is not working in the same way as the solution. Please check once the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You do not need two booleans to do this

```
<button ng-click="DataLbl= false">Data 1</button> 
<button ng-click="DataLbl= true">Data 2</button> 
<h2 ng-hide="DataLbl"  >This is mah Data1, yo!</h2>
<h2 ng-hide="!DataLbl"  >This is mah Data2, yo!</h2>
```

Comment: Here I use only one boolean, DataLbl for 'DataLabel'. Try it. Do not forget the ngController div which I did not include

Comment: Your solution will make both buttons do the same thing... clicking Data 2 a second time will show Data 1 again. I don't think that's what he wants.

Comment: I have a thrid button which is not working in the same way as the solution. Please check once the updated question

Comment: @TomShen u r correct, should use false and then true instead of !DataLbl on the button tags. I did the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <li><a data-ng-click="Data1=true;Data2=false" href="">ALL PROJECTS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-ng-click="Data2=true;Data1=false" href="">NOTIFICATIONS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN' ; Data1=true;" href="">SAVED PROJECTS</a>
  </li>

  <div class="wrapper" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h2 ng-show="Data1">This is mah Data1, yo!</h2>
    <h2 ng-show="Data2">This is mah Data2, yo!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not need 2 booleans to do this, see my solution.

Comment: I toggled div on button click.  and he wanted to show div on click. in your case once of the div is always visible

Comment: true, I guess it all depends on what he wants to do

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have added a third button and now it is not working the same way as solution

Comment: Just remove comma inside data-ng-click and put semicolon instead.
`<a data-ng-click="search.status = 'OPEN' ; Data1=true;" href="">SAVED PROJECTS</a>`

Comment: I will update the actuall list tag in 1min. Please check once again

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @updated the question. Please have a look. The third button when clicked not showing data

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114357/discussion-between-krupesh-kotecha-and-satyadev).